# why HashMap Values are not cast in List?

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, hashmap

I'm putting values into the hashmap which is of the form,

```
Map<Long, Double> highLowValueMap=new HashMap<Long, Double>();
highLowValueMap.put(1l, 10.0);
highLowValueMap.put(2l, 20.0);
```

I want to create a list by using `values()` method of map.

```
List<Double> valuesToMatch=new ArrayList<>();
valuesToMatch=(List<Double>) highLowValueMap.values();
```

or

```
List<Double> valuesToMatch=(List<Double>) highLowValueMap.values();
```

However, it throws an exception:

> Exception in thread "main" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   java.util.HashMap$Values cannot be cast to java.util.List

But it allows me to pass it in to the creation of a list:

```
List<Double> valuesToMatch  = new ArrayList<Double>( highLowValueMap.values());
```

Comment: The `values` method returns a collection, not a list.

Answer (score 161, accepted):

## TL;DR

```
List<V> al = new ArrayList<V>(hashMapVar.values());
```

## Explanation

Because `HashMap#values()` returns a `java.util.Collection<V>` and you can't cast a `Collection` into an `ArrayList`, thus you get `ClassCastException`.

I'd suggest using `ArrayList(Collection<? extends V>)` constructor. This constructor accepts an object which implements `Collection<? extends V>` as an argument. You won't get `ClassCastException` when you pass the result of `HashMap.values()` like this:

```
List<V> al = new ArrayList<V>(hashMapVar.values());
```

## Going further into the Java API source code

**HashMap#values():** Check the return type in the source, and ask yourself, can a `java.util.Collection` be casted into `java.util.ArrayList`? No

```
public Collection<V> values() {
    Collection<V> vs = values;
    return (vs != null ? vs : (values = new Values()));
}
```

**ArrayList(Collection):** Check the argument type in the source. Can a method which argument is a super type accepts sub type? Yes

```
public ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c) {
    elementData = c.toArray();
    size = elementData.length;
    // c.toArray might (incorrectly) not return Object[] (see 6260652)
    if (elementData.getClass() != Object[].class)
        elementData = Arrays.copyOf(elementData, size, Object[].class);
}
```

Answer (score 27):

The answer can be found by reading the JavaDoc

The `values()` method returns a `Collection`

So

```
List<Double> valuesToMatch=(List<Double>) highLowValueMap.values();
```

Should be

```
Collection<Double> valuesToMatch= highLowValueMap.values();
```

You can still iterate over this collection as you would a list.

http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#values%28%29

---

This works:

```
List<Double> valuesToMatch  = new ArrayList<Double>( highLowValueMap.values() );
```

Because `ArrayList` has a constructor that accepts a collection.

Answer (score 6):

It's because `values()` returns `Collection` which according to source code of `HashMap` is of type `AbstractCollection` and thus cannot be cast to `List`.

You are able to instantiate `ArrayList` passing it `values()` result because `ArrayList` constructor can take `Collection` as its argument.

Answer (score 5):

If you have already created an instance of your List subtype (e.g., ArrayList, LinkedList), you could use the addAll method.

e.g.,

```
valuesToMatch.addAll(myCollection)
```

Many list subtypes can also take the source collection in their constructor.

Answer (score 2):

Have you check the API, what is returned by [`values()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html#values%28%29) method? And what ArrayList [constructor](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html#ArrayList%28java.util.Collection%29) accepts?

Answer (score 2):

I faced the same issue, But then I realised the values() return Collection, and not a List.
But we are able to instantiate a new ArrayList like this :

List valuesToMatch  = new ArrayList(highLowValueMap.values());

Because ArrayList has a constructor that can take Collection as its argument.

Answer (score 1):

Well it's because your values are really a HashSet. 
You could write a code like this to iterate over the set:

```
List<Double> valuesToMatch=new ArrayList<>();
for(Double d : highLowValueMap.values(){
  valuesToMatch.put(d);
}
```

Comment: Nope, `values()` method returns a `Collection` and `keySet()` returns a `Set`. http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/HashMap.html

Comment: You add items to ArrrayList via add, not put, which is for Set.

Answer (score 1):

`Values` is an inner class in `HashMap` class (see $ symbol in `java.util.HashMap$Values`).
 HashMap.values() method will return  `Values` class's object which is not implementing `List` interface. So is the `ClassCastException`.  
Here is the `Values` inner private class  in HashMap which is not implementing `List` interface. Even AbstractCollection is also not implementing `List` interface.
`AbstractCollection` implements `Collection` interface. So not able to cast to `List`.

```
private final class Values extends AbstractCollection<V> {
        public Iterator<V> iterator() {
            return newValueIterator();
        }
        public int size() {
            return size;
        }
        public boolean contains(Object o) {
            return containsValue(o);
        }
        public void clear() {
            HashMap.this.clear();
        }
    }
```

**Update**

Following is one of the constructor in ArrayList.

```
public ArrayList(Collection<? extends E> c) {
        elementData = c.toArray();
        size = elementData.length;
        // c.toArray might (incorrectly) not return Object[] (see 6260652)
        if (elementData.getClass() != Object[].class)
            elementData = Arrays.copyOf(elementData, size, Object[].class);
    }
```

So `hashmapObj.values()` method return type is `Collection`. Now which class is implementing this Collection interface ? Answer is `Values` class which is inside the HashMap class (inner class). Returned value from `hashmapObj.values()` can be passed to above ArrayList constructor which is valid.

Even following is valid statements.

```
HashMap<String, String> map  = new HashMap<String, String>();
Collection c = map.values();
```

But following statements are incorrect

```
HashMap<String, String> map  = new HashMap<String, String>();
List c = map.values(); //compilation error.. return type is not List
```

Comment: Your answer is the most understandable. I couldn't understand why I can do `Collection<String> c = new ArrayList<>();` but couldn't cast `values()` to that type or even `List`.

Comment: @ ashur This is because this way you code to interface, which is acceptable. You can change Collection to List (as it's an interface too) in your example, and it's still OK, but you cannot cast to interface.

Answer (score 1):

I doubt the selected best answer, where it says:
"Because HashMap#values() returns a java.util.Collection and you can't cast a Collection into an ArrayList, thus you get ClassCastException."

It's not because Collection can't be casted to ArrayList, the real reason is that the Collection returned by HashMap.values() is backed up by the inner class HashMap.Values. And HashMap.Values is not a super class of ArrayList.

Answer (score -1):

To convert the values from a Map instance to a list you could use `Iterable<T>.map`

```
val yourList: List<Any> = #Map.values.map { it }
```

Comment: This is not Java.

Comment: By interoperability of JVM could serve