# Type mismatch: cannot convert from List<Map<String,Object>> to List<Object>

Tags: java, spring, jdbctemplate

We have

```
 String sql = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = '" +userId +"'";
 List<Object> userList = template.queryForList(sql);
```

The query shall return the different users with the given id.
The `template` is an object of `JdbcTemplate` class.
Here the query  returns a List of `Map<String,Object>` and the left hand side is `List<Object>`. Is there any way to do the conversion. This is part of the spring transaction management example.

Comment: Just curious, what do you mean when you say "I guess it returns"? Not sure of return type itself?

Comment: Then my solution does works for this case. Let me know if there are any issues.

Answer (score 2):

You can always use only the `values` which you are interested in the first place like:

```
List<Object> userList = new ArrayList<Object>(template.queryForList(sql).values());
```

In case it returns `List<Map<String, Object>>` instead of `Map<String,Object>`:

```
List < Object > userList = new ArrayList < Object > ();
for (Map < String, Object > obj: template.queryForList(sql)) {
    userList.addAll(obj.values());
}
```

This should give you a list of `Object` as you need. If you need to explore why `Map.values()` cannot be directly casted to list and we need to create a new `ArrayList` for that purpose can be found here: [why HashMap Values are not cast in List](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15522546/why-hashmap-values-are-not-cast-in-list)

Comment: I am receiving the following error:
The method values() is undefined for the type List<Map<String,Object>>.

Comment: So it is returning List<Map<String,Object>> and not Map<String,Object> as mentioned by you in question.

Comment: Updated the solution accordingly.

Answer (score 1):

I think you should take another approach. Spring can not build objects from the data returned from the database, but you can use a `RowMapper` to construct user objects. Additionally you should not build the query on your own but use `PreparedStatement`s. Otherwise you might be vulnerable to SQL injection.

Here is a example on how to do it:

```
template.query("SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = ?", new Object[] { userId }, new RowMapper<User>() {

    public User mapRow(ResultSet rs, int rowNum) {
        // Build a user from the current row and return it
    }

});
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, was curious what should be done in case when Users class has an object as instance variable then how can the value received from the database will be usable in setting the value of that instance variable as the database does not consists that object rather it just contains a VARCHAR or NUMBER value.

Comment: I don't really know what you mean. Please add your `User` class and the structure of the corresponding table to your question if you need further assistance.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have confused it a lot. The best way to do it is indeed what is suggested by Steffen Kreutz. Consider the following example:

User Table in DB has following fields:

```
1. UserID -> Type: Int
2. User_Name -> Type: Varchar
3. User_Contact -> Type: Varchar
...
```

Now, you can simple write a RowMapper to map all these fields to your custom POJO Object like follows:

POJO Class:

```
public class User{
     private int userId;
     private String userName;
     private String userContact;

     public int getUserId() {
          return this.userId;
     }

     public void setUserId(int userId) {
          this.userId = userId;
     }

     /* Other Getter-Setter(s) */
}
```

Query String:

```
private static final String SELECT_QUERY = "SELECT * FROM user WHERE id = ?";
```

JdbcTemplate Call:
Here you are passing `userId` for ?. JdbcTemplate will automatically take care of it.

```
List<User> = (List<User>) jdbcTemplate.query(SELECT_QUERY, new Object[] { userId }, new UserRowMapper());
```

Finally the UserRowMapper Class:

```
class UserRowMapper implements RowMapper {

  @Override
  public Object mapRow(ResultSet resultSet, int row) throws SQLException {
    User user = new User();

    user.setUserId(resultSet.getInt("UserID"));
    user.setUserName(resultSet.getString("User_Name"));
    user.setUserContact(resultSet.getString("User_Contact"));

    return user;
  }
}
```

This is indeed the best and recommended way of using JdbcTemplate.